# How to limit Facebook Friend list to a certain number on response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following fetches friend-list of a logged in user, but how do i only fetch 5 friends not the entire list of a user's friends.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'name,id,location,birthday'}, function(response){
      if (response && response.data){
          $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                $('#FBFirendsDiv').append(friend.name);
            });
      } else {
        console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using limit parameter.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/

me?fields=id,name,friends.limit(10)

Comment: and where do i put that limit on the code above? where on the code exactly?